# determining solution to PDE with Mathematica

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, bugs, modeling

**Bug introduced in or after 10.3, persisting through 11.2.**

---

It's been a while since I have touched separation of variable and not too keen to "get my hands dirty" if I may avoid it.

> The given PDE is $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$
>
> coupled with the initial and boundary conditions:
>
> $u_{x}\left ( 0,t \right )-u\left ( 0,t \right )=0$
>
> $u\left ( 1,t \right )=0$
>
> $u\left ( x,0 \right )=f\left ( x \right )$

Direct computation with Mathematica deduce the solution to be

```
DSolve[{D[u[x, t], t] == D[u[x, t], {x, 2}], 
D[u[0, t], x] - u[0, t] == 0, D[u[1, t]] == 0, u[x, 0] == f[x]}, 
u[x, t], {x, t}]
```

which is not in synced with my "pen and paper" solution.

Would someone be kind enough to verify that Mathematica is giving the right output?

Comment: MMA has no information about f[x] , consequently it gives a solution with the restriction `Integrate[f[x] Sin[\[Pi] x K[1]], {x, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> True]`. A comparable restriction I would expect in your "pen and paper" (? to secret to show?) solution.

Comment: @Nasser Typological error

Comment: @Nasser I am going to correct this.

Comment: Bug still present in M11.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> which is not in synced with my "pen and paper" solution.

You did not show your solution. May be you can share this with us?

But looking at it, I could not verify Mathematica solution.

But ignoring this for now, I Just looked at the eigenvalues it used. For simplicity, let $f(x)=x$. This does not affect the eigenvalues. We see

```
ClearAll[u, x, t]
pde = D[u[x, t], t] == D[u[x, t], {x, 2}];
ic = u[x, 0] == x;
bc = {D[u[0, t], x] - u[0, t] == 0, D[u[1, t]] == 0};
sol = First@DSolve[{pde, ic, bc}, u[x, t], {x, t}];
sol = u[x, t] /. sol /. {K[1] -> n, Infinity -> 20}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So Mathematica is saying the eigenvalues $\lambda_n= (n \pi)^2$ and the eigenfunctions are $\sin(\sqrt \lambda_n x)$. So Mathematica is saying the first few eigenvalues are

```
 Table[(n Pi)^2,{n,1,6}]//N
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But by solving this by hand, the eigenvalues are the solution to

$$
   \tan(\sqrt \lambda) = \frac{1}{\sqrt \lambda}
$$

And this does not have closed form solution. The first few eigenvalues are

```
   lam/.NSolve[Tan[Sqrt[lam]]==1/Sqrt[lam]&&0<lam<130,lam]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Also, I get the eignfunctions as combination of $\cos$ and $\sin$ and not just $\sin$.  So I have no idea how Mathematica obtained this solution.  ALso, plotting the numerical solutions vs. analytical, show they are different

(NDSolve gives warning initial and boundary conditions are inconsistent at end points. But this is becuase I picked $f(x)=x$ for initial conditions. This can be ignored for now, it does not affect the overall solution for $t>0$).

```
ClearAll[u, x, t]
pde = D[u[x, t], t] == D[u[x, t], {x, 2}];
ic = u[x, 0] == x;
bc = {D[u[0, t], x] - u[0, t] == 0, D[u[1, t]] == 0};
sol = First@DSolve[{pde, ic, bc}, u[x, t], {x, t}];
sol = u[x, t] /. sol /. {K[1] -> n, Infinity -> 20};
solN = NDSolve[{pde, ic, bc}, u, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}];
Manipulate[
 Plot[{Evaluate[Activate[sol] /. t -> t0], 
   Evaluate[u[x, t] /. solN /. t -> t0]}, {x, 0, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 1}}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"DSolve", "NDSolve"}],
 {{t0, 0.001, "time"}, 0, 1, .01}
 ]
```

[image]

### Hand solution for first part

Solve
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}  &  =\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial x^{2}}\\
\frac{\partial u\left(  0,t\right)  }{\partial x}-u\left(  0,t\right)   &
=0\\
\frac{\partial u\left(  L,t\right)  }{\partial x}  &  =0\\
u\left(  x,0\right)   &  =f\left(  x\right)
\end{align*}

Let $u\left(  x,t\right)  =X\left(  x\right)  T\left(  t\right)  $, which
gives the $X\left(  x\right)  $ ODE as

\begin{align*}
X^{\prime\prime}+\lambda X  &  =0\\
X^{\prime}\left(  0\right)  -X\left(  0\right)   &  =0\\
X^{\prime}\left(  L\right)   &  =0
\end{align*}

Assuming $\lambda<0$, then solution is

$$
X\left(  x\right)  =c_{1}\cosh\left(  \sqrt{\lambda}x\right)  +c_{2}
\sinh\left(  \sqrt{\lambda}x\right)
$$

Then

$$
X^{\prime}\left(  x\right)  =c_{1}\sqrt{\lambda}\sinh\left(  \sqrt{\lambda
}x\right)  +c_{2}\sqrt{\lambda}\cosh\left(  \sqrt{\lambda}x\right)
$$

At $x=0$

\begin{align*}
0 &  =X^{\prime}\left(  0\right)  -X\left(  0\right)  \\
&  =c_{2}\sqrt{\lambda}-c_{1}\\
c_{1} &  =c_{2}\sqrt{\lambda}
\end{align*}

Second B.C. gives

\begin{align*}
0  & =X^{\prime}\left(  L\right)  \\
0  & =c_{1}\sqrt{\lambda}\sinh\left(  \sqrt{\lambda}L\right)
\end{align*}

But this mean $c_{1}=0$ since $\sinh\left(  \sqrt{\lambda}L\right)  $ can't be
zero. Therefore $c_{2}$ is also zero. Hence $\lambda<0$ not possible eigenvalue.

Assuming $\lambda=0$ then the solution

\begin{align*}
X\left(  x\right)   &  =c_{1}x+c_{2}\\
X^{\prime}\left(  x\right)   &  =c_{1}
\end{align*}

First B.C. gives

\begin{align*}
0  &  =X^{\prime}\left(  0\right)  -X\left(  0\right) \\
&  =c_{1}-c_{2}\\
c_{1}  &  =c_{2}
\end{align*}

Second B.C. gives

\begin{align*}
0  &  =X^{\prime}\left(  L\right) \\
&  =c_{1}
\end{align*}

Hence $c_{1}=0$ and $c_{2}=0$. Trivial solution. Therefore $\lambda=0$ is not
an eigenvalue.

Assuming $\lambda>0$, then solution is

\begin{align*}
X\left(  x\right)   &  =c_{1}\cos\left(  \sqrt{\lambda}x\right)  +c_{2}
\sin\left(  \sqrt{\lambda}x\right) \\
X^{\prime}\left(  x\right)   &  =-\sqrt{\lambda}c_{1}\sin\left(  \sqrt
{\lambda}x\right)  +\sqrt{\lambda}c_{2}\cos\left(  \sqrt{\lambda}x\right)
\end{align*}

First B.C. gives

\begin{align}
0  &  =X^{\prime}\left(  0\right)  -X\left(  0\right) \nonumber\\
&  =\sqrt{\lambda}c_{2}-c_{1}\nonumber\\
c_{1}  &  =\sqrt{\lambda}c_{2} \tag{1}
\end{align}

Second B.C. gives

\begin{align}
0  &  =X^{\prime}\left(  L\right) \nonumber\\
&  =-\sqrt{\lambda}c_{1}\sin\left(  \sqrt{\lambda}L\right)  +\sqrt{\lambda
}c_{2}\cos\left(  \sqrt{\lambda}L\right)  \tag{2}
\end{align}

Plugging (1) into (2) gives

\begin{align*}
0  &  =-\sqrt{\lambda}\sqrt{\lambda}c_{2}\sin\left(  \sqrt{\lambda}L\right)
+\sqrt{\lambda}c_{2}\cos\left(  \sqrt{\lambda}L\right) \\
0  &  =c_{2}\left(  -\lambda\sin\left(  \sqrt{\lambda}L\right)  +\sqrt
{\lambda}\cos\left(  \sqrt{\lambda}L\right)  \right)
\end{align*}

For non-trivial solution, we want $-\lambda\sin\left(  \sqrt{\lambda}L\right)
+\sqrt{\lambda}\cos\left(  \sqrt{\lambda}L\right)  =0$ or

\begin{align*}
-\lambda\tan\left(  \sqrt{\lambda}L\right)  +\sqrt{\lambda}  &  =0\\
\tan\left(  \sqrt{\lambda}L\right)   &  =\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}}
\end{align*}

Eigenvalues $\lambda_{n}$ are given by solution to the above trig equation.
There is no closed form solution. Hence eigenfunctions are

$$
X_{n}\left(  x\right)  =c_{n}\left(  \sqrt{\lambda_{n}}\cos\left(
\sqrt{\lambda_{n}}x\right)  +\sin\left(  \sqrt{\lambda_{n}}x\right)  \right)
$$

**Update**

The eigenfuntion (solution to the space boundary value ODE) can be verified using Mathematica 11.2 as follows

```
ClearAll[y,x,lam];
DSolve[{y''[x]+ lam y[x]==0,y'[0]-y[0]==0,y'[1]==0},y[x],x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The above shows that the eigenvalues are the solution to

```
    lam Sin[Sqrt[lam]]==Sqrt[lam] Cos[Sqrt[lam]]
```

Which agree with the above hand solution.

Comment: There is an unfortunate error in your working. 
"at x=0:.....", Cosh(0) =1

Comment: @Physkid thanks. Corrected. It does not affect the solution. Negative Eigenvalue still remain not valid.